# Исчезает форматирование текста строкового ресурса

Tags: android

Собственно сам код вывода текста описан здесь: [TextSwitcher как реализовать прокрутку назад](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/486329/textswitcher-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4). Сами строковые ресурсы R.string.about1,R.string.about2,R.string.about3 содержат форматирование, что-то вроде такого текста:

```
This is <b> a cap of tea</b>\n
<i>tea</i> - неисчисляемое существительное
```

В итоге в приложении строки разбиваются, но форматирование вообще никак не отражается.
Пробовала установить форматирование как рекомендовали в этом ответе [форматирование текста в string.xml](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/458533/%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-string-xml)
Но проект не компилируется, выдает ошибку (даже с примером из ответа, где меняется цвет текста).
Приложение на API15.
Может, кто подскажет, как эту проблему решить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getResources().getString(R.string.id)` - возвращает строку без форматирования
`getResources().getText(R.string.id)` - возвращает строку с форматированием

Так что у вас проблема не в том как вы задаёте форматирование, а в том как его получить пытаетесь.